# In React.js app, using AWS amplify cognito for sign-in sign-out, how to re-ceck access Token after every 15 to 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my project, we are using aws amplify and cognito services for sign-in & sign-out where my access token is valid for 60 minutes and refresh token is valid for 7 days.

Issue is --> if, during this 60 minutes, I revoke my refresh token ( which invalidates my access token ) via postman, my user is not being logged out before 60 minute. He continues to use that ongoing session...

Normal sign-out is working (local storage clean up) but this 1 scenario does not.

So, Is there a way AWS handles it? Do i have to custom code to re-check access token every 20 to 15 minutes? how to handle this scenario ?

What should I do as I am completely clueless here.